# Pull all 8 digit numbers from a data frame

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have this assignment where I need to pull all the 8 digit numbers from a text file. I've converted the text file into a dataframe and now have some 67 columns with 18000 rows. There are empty cells as well.

Within this table, some 8 digit number exist, (not in any particular row or column) which is what I want to extract.

I need all these numbers to be extracted into one single column without checking for duplicates.

The only code I've written so far:

```
data <- read.delim("cerupload_adsi_1_01-02-2019.txt", header = FALSE, sep="|")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `regmatches()` and match for a juxtaposition of exactly 8 digits with regex `"\\d{8}"`. Specifying word boundaries `"\\b"` might make this more robust.

#### Example

```
txt <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore 235462354 magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At 
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita 235 kasd gubergren, no sea 
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 12345678 Lorem ipsum dolor 345.454 sit amet, 
12345678 consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 345 voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita 12345.67 12345.678 kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus 
est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 12345678"

regmatches(txt, gregexpr("\\b\\d{8}\\b", txt))
# [[1]]
# [1] "12345678" "12345678" "12345678"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, put all of your data into a simple integer vector:

```
data = as.integer(unlist(data))
```

Next, remove any elements that weren't convertible to integers (optional):

```
data = data[!is.na(data)]
```

Next, find the integers that are 8 characters long:

```
data = data[nchar(as.character(data))==8]
```

Then, make a data.frame with the integer vector as a column:

```
data = data.frame(x=data)
```

Comment: Copied the same but the final result shows 0 observations which is not right

Comment: Strange because it works when I do the same. Probably our input data is different. Mine is a data.frame with integer or numeric columns, or else character columns containing only numeric digits.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_extract_all` from `stringr`

```
temp <- data.frame(col = unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(unlist(data), "\\d{8}$")))
temp

#       col
#1 12352318
#2 98765432
```

**data**

Tested on this sample data with two columns.

```
data <- data.frame(a = "This is a text with number 1234 and 12352318", 
                   b = "More random text 123456789 98765432")
```